# DirectX Texture Clean-up in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, iterator, directx, resource-cleanup

I am currently working on a game in C++ using DirectX. The engine was given to us by a professor at my school, and I have been inspecting memory leaks in his engine and I believe I have traced them back to this method. To start, it wasn't even being called, and now that it's being called I am unsure if this is the correct way to completely delete and clean up textures loaded by DirectX.

Here is the method being called on the `TextureManager`:

```
void DirectXTextureManager::clear()
{
    map<wchar_t*, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9>::iterator it;
    map<wchar_t*, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9>::iterator itToErase;
    it = textures->begin();
    while (it != textures->end())
    {
    wchar_t *keyToDelete = (*it).first;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 textureToDelete = (*it).second;
    itToErase = it;
    it++;
    textures->erase(itToErase);
    delete keyToDelete;
    textureToDelete->Release();
    textureToDelete = NULL;
    }

    stringTable->emptyStringTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the textures part everything seems fine - it is enough to call `Release()` on the `LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE` object to free it:

```
LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 textureToDelete = (*it).second;
...
textureToDelete->Release();
```

I'm a bit worried about `stringTable` - is it the part responsible for `wchar_t*` in the map keys? If so, you should check what `stringTable->emptyStringTable()` does, maybe there's no need to delete the keys manually.

Comment: I think it's probably something to do with that call to emptyStringTable() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Does `DirectXTextureManager` have any other methods that call `Release()` on any textures?

If it does, then perhaps there is no need to call `clear()`. In particular, check whether the class destructor or some other "`UniInitialize()`" method exists that may already do the cleanup. Personally, I also prefer to use the `SAFE_RELEASE()` macro from the `DXUT` headers since is checks if the pointer is non-null before calling Release and sets it to NULL afterwards.

Finally, you might find debugging easier with the output from the DirectX debug run-time that is controlled from the "DirectX Control Panel" (installed with the SDK). It will output very good logging to the VisualStudio output window including details of unreleased resources on shutdown that you can use to troubleshoot the code.